# Peavey SP-2A Speaker Repair

Tags: repair, speakers

I'm taking a shot in the dark here but I have these old Peavey Sp-2A speakers that I'm looking at fixing. They were a gift to me a long time ago and since then the main loudspeaker, or sub-woofer, has gone out. Or at least I think. I'm getting sound out of the tweeter, which is the top part, but I'm not getting any sound out of the lower speaker. I've seen what looks to be replacement speakers on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004LRP2OW). I have two of these bad boys and I love their look so I want to keep them. These are used for vocals, guitars, and keys so I want to make sure they sound good. The cabinets are in good shape but since the paint is chipping I am considering sanding them down and covering them in black carpet. I'm just curious to see if I'm approaching this repair the right way or if there are better speaker replacement options that would not go over $400 for the pair to repair.

[image: Peavey SP-2A Speaker]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacements would appear to be black widows, 15", 8 ohms, with more power capacity than the originals, which should also be black widows. Good speakers ! First check the drivers out of circuit, using a small battery. 9v will do. When it's connected to the speaker, the cone should move out or in. If not, it needs changing. If it moves, it should either be the crossover circuit or the wiring 'twixt it, the input on the cab., and the speaker.

Answer (score 2):

Take the front grille off and do a visual.  Ancient speakers often have the rubber "surround" (which holds the cone to the internal faceplate) crumble into dust.  Luckily, it's easy to get replacements in kits which include detailed instructions, matching glue, etc.  I fixed my Advent speakers this way.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that if the speakers are blown, there maybe damage in the filtering coils in the crossovers, examine to see if there are melted or deformed spools on these coils. You can order needed parts from peavey or rebuild the coils yourself by counting the coils as you unwrap them and then rewinding the coils using the same type and gauge of wire. I've always been amazed at what overpowering can do to a speaker system.

Answer (score 0):

SP2a peavey speakers came with 18" "black widow" speakers.Replacement cones (spiders) come from Peavey,the only way to go

Imagine what kind of idiot could blow a 300 watt speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that if the speakers are blown, there maybe damage in the filtering coils in the crossovers, examine to see if there are melted or deformed spools on these coils. You can order needed parts from peavey or rebuild the coils yourself by counting the coils as you unwrap them and then rewinding the coils using the same type and gauge of wire. I've always been amazed at what overpowering can do to a speaker system. Also, it appears that the phone jacks on the crossover panel are dirty and corroded. The crossover is wired so that the signal passes through the Bi-Amp phone jacks when they have nothing plugged into them, but dirt and corrosion can block the signal making the speaker silent. If you check this, you might find no need to replace the speaker. Just saying...